# An unexpected behavior arises when clicking the edit or add button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my React app, I've incorporated data fetching from the Reqres API. Despite confirming a single invocation during the initial component mount, an unexpected behavior arises when clicking the edit or add button, leading to an additional API call. Investigating the cause and resolving the issue is my current focus.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { removePerson } from '../actions/Slice';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { addPerson } from '../actions/Slice';

export default function Home() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((totaldata) => {
                const users = totaldata.data.map(user => ({
                    id: user.id,
                    first: user.first_name,
                    last: user.last_name,
                    email: user.email

                }));
                users.forEach(user => dispatch(addPerson(user)));

            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
    }, []);
    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        if (window.confirm("Delete the item?")) {
            dispatch(removePerson(id))
        } else {
            alert("Cancelled")
        }

    }
    const addclick = () => {
        navigate('/addUser');
    };
    const people = useSelector(state => state.people);
    const search = useSelector(state => state.searchQuery);


    const filteredPeople = people.filter(
        (person) =>
            person.first && person.first.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <h1 className='emp'>Student Data</h1>
            <table id='customers'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Users Action</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {filteredPeople.map((pop, index) =>
                    (
                        <tr key={`${pop.id}_${index}`}>
                            <td>{pop.first}</td>
                            <td>{pop.last}</td>
                            <td>{pop.email}</td>
                            <td>{pop.phone}</td>
                            <td>{pop.gender}</td>
                            <td>{pop.option}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button className="edit-button" onClick={() => navigate(`/editUser/${pop.id}`)} >Edit</button>
                                <button className="delete-button" onClick={() => handleDelete(pop.id)}>Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}


                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="add">
                <button className="add-button" onClick={addclick}>Add User</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Send a screenshots of your network tab.

Comment: https://postimg.cc/F1dC9WCn please check

Comment: Please click on the 'disable cache' and try again. I can't say without looking to code, But you can try by disabling cache in network tab.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file where your `<App />` component is being renderred (`index.js`, `main.js`...), if it's running in strict mode:

```
    <React.StrictMode>
     <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
```

Because if it is, that might be the reason your api is called twice.